# Merging branches into working copy?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

I am using Subversion to manage code for a web app. There are shared dev/QA servers and each one is a working copy of the trunk of the project.

In order to push changes to these shared sites I am merging from branches (each of which is up to date with trunk) into the working copies.

Many times I get conflicts on files that are not modified in the source branch. Also I'm getting tree conflicts on items added to the trunk but not added to the branch... why isn't it just skipping that?

I'm aware that merging to working copies is probably not a good idea but the shared environments thing is a requirement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally I'd merge the changes into a clean checkout, commit the merge then update the working copies to pick-up the changes - is that an option?

Comment: Well it's a working copy of trunk, so I don't want to commit there. But are you envisioning a different trunk/branching policy?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you're doing now. You could always branch trunk for each deployment then merge your feature / fixes into that branch and then use update to pick up the changes. I'm not sure why you'd get conflicts though unless trunk and the fix branch had diverged. Do you have a small reproducible case you can post?

Comment: svnmerge (http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) simplified the two-way merging that our teams do - it keeps track of merged and blocked revisions from multiple sources and prevents common mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since been using an environment branch in addition to release branches.